# Security Lack: Pull requests from forks triggering continuous integration

Tags: security, github, continuous-integration

I like to use Azure Pipelines or Travis CI for running build and test jobs.
It is also nice to use several deployment steps which are e.g. only executed when running jobs for branch `master`. Therefor I normally use environment variables to enable CI to deploy.

Actually there is a security issue with doing so: A hacker could

- fork my repository *and*
- edit the `.travis.yml` or `azure-pipelines.yml` in a way that CI will abuse the secrets from environment variables to do evil things. *After this the hacker can*
- create a pull request from the fork repository to my repository *such that*
- Travis or Azure Pipelines will execute that harmful code and possibly destroy something.

Is there any solution for this issue in the sense that

- I can still enjoy the benefits of automatic deploy *and*
- no possible hacker can abuse CI?

One way to handle this could be to disable triggering builds for the case of pull requests from forks. Is there such a feature for GitHub.com? I did not find anything on this topic.
Or is there any other way to achieve the goal?

Comment: I know with GitHub Actions secrets aren't available with pull requests from forks, so this isn't a problem.  You can check the documentation for Travis CI and Azure Pipelines to see if they have similar features.

Answer (score 0):

Like @bk2204 said,
this information is available in the documentation.

#### For Travis

the docu says that for these "external pull request" builds coming from forks, secrets will not be available, only for "internal pull requests" from the original repository.

See: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/

#### For Azure Pipelines:

Microsoft's azure pipelines already has a checkbox where one can enable or disable availability of secrets for pull requests from forks:

- Select your pipeline
- Click `Edit` on the upper right corner
- Click the three dots on the upper right corner
- Select `Triggers`
- Click below `Pull request validation` on the left.
- On the right you can configure if jobs should run at all and if secrets can be used